# how to use bazel compile tensorflow demo with custom toolchain in Ubuntu

Tags: tensorflow, cross-platform

I compiled tensorflow with custom toolchain as the website https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/wiki/Building-with-a-custom-toolchain.
but it can't work, Please help me to solve it.

shell:

> bazel build --crosstool_top=//tools/arm_compiler:toolchain
>   --cpu=armeabi-v7a tensorflow/examples/speech_commands:test_streaming_accuracy

The error log as below,:

> ERROR:
>   /home/billy/.cache/bazel/_bazel_billy/b6316091758c6a5954b4681b7e92ef65/external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/BUILD:12:1:
>   Target '//tools/arm_compiler:cc-compiler-local' is not visible from
>   target '@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:stl'. Check the visibility declaration
>   of the former target if you think the dependency is legitimate ERROR:
>   Analysis of target
>   '//tensorflow/examples/speech_commands:test_streaming_accuracy'
>   failed; build aborted: Analysis of target
>   '@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:stl' failed; build aborted INFO: Elapsed
>   time: 0.325s FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (1 packages
>   loaded)
>       currently loading: @protobuf_archive//

WORKSPACE:

```
  workspace(name = "org_tensorflow")

http_archive(
    name = "io_bazel_rules_closure",
    sha256 = "6691c58a2cd30a86776dd9bb34898b041e37136f2dc7e24cadaeaf599c95c657",
    strip_prefix = "rules_closure-08039ba8ca59f64248bb3b6ae016460fe9c9914f",
    urls = [
        "https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/rules_closure/archive/08039ba8ca59f64248bb3b6ae016460fe9c9914f.tar.gz",
        "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_closure/archive/08039ba8ca59f64248bb3b6ae016460fe9c9914f.tar.gz",  # 2018-01-16
    ],
)

load("@io_bazel_rules_closure//closure:defs.bzl", "closure_repositories")

closure_repositories()

load("//tensorflow:workspace.bzl", "tf_workspace")

# Uncomment and update the paths in these entries to build the Android demo.
android_sdk_repository(
    name = "androidsdk",
    api_level = 23,
    # Ensure that you have the build_tools_version below installed in the
    # SDK manager as it updates periodically.
    build_tools_version = "26.0.2",
    # Replace with path to Android SDK on your system
    path = "/usr/local/android_sdk",
)

android_ndk_repository(
    name="androidndk",
    path="/usr/local/android-ndk-r12b",
    # This needs to be 14 or higher to compile TensorFlow.
    # Please specify API level to >= 21 to build for 64-bit
    # archtectures or the Android NDK will automatically select biggest
    # API level that it supports without notice.
    # Note that the NDK version is not the API level.
    api_level=14)

# Please add all new TensorFlow dependencies in workspace.bzl.
tf_workspace()

new_http_archive(
    name = "inception_v1",
    build_file = "models.BUILD",
    sha256 = "7efe12a8363f09bc24d7b7a450304a15655a57a7751929b2c1593a71183bb105",
    urls = [
        "http://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/inception_v1.zip",
        "http://download.tensorflow.org/models/inception_v1.zip",
    ],
)

new_http_archive(
    name = "mobile_ssd",
    build_file = "models.BUILD",
    sha256 = "bddd81ea5c80a97adfac1c9f770e6f55cbafd7cce4d3bbe15fbeb041e6b8f3e8",
    urls = [
        "http://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/ssd_mobilenet_v1_android_export.zip",
        "http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/ssd_mobilenet_v1_android_export.zip",
    ],
)

new_http_archive(
    name = "mobile_multibox",
    build_file = "models.BUILD",
    sha256 = "859edcddf84dddb974c36c36cfc1f74555148e9c9213dedacf1d6b613ad52b96",
    urls = [
        "http://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/mobile_multibox_v1a.zip",
        "http://download.tensorflow.org/models/mobile_multibox_v1a.zip",
    ],
)

new_http_archive(
    name = "stylize",
    build_file = "models.BUILD",
    sha256 = "3d374a730aef330424a356a8d4f04d8a54277c425e274ecb7d9c83aa912c6bfa",
    urls = [
        "http://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/stylize_v1.zip",
        "http://download.tensorflow.org/models/stylize_v1.zip",
    ],
)



new_http_archive(
    name = "speech_commands",
    build_file = "models.BUILD",
    sha256 = "c3ec4fea3158eb111f1d932336351edfe8bd515bb6e87aad4f25dbad0a600d0c",
    urls = [
        "http://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/speech_commands_v0.01.zip",
        "http://download.tensorflow.org/models/speech_commands_v0.01.zip",
    ],
)

new_http_archive(
    name = 'linaroLinuxGcc49Repo',
    build_file = 'compilers/linaro_linux_gcc_5.5.BUILD',
    url = 'http://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest-5/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gcc-linaro-5.5.0-2017.10-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz',
    strip_prefix = 'gcc-linaro-5.5.0-2017.10-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf',
)
```

arm_compiler/BUILD:

```
# This is the entry point for --crosstool_top.
#
# The cc_toolchain rule used is found by:
#
# 1. Finding the appropriate toolchain in the CROSSTOOL file based on the --cpu
#    and --compiler command line flags (if they exist, otherwise using the
#    "default_target_cpu" / "default_toolchain" fields in the CROSSTOOL file)
# 2. Concatenating the "target_cpu" and "compiler" fields of the toolchain in
#    use and using that as a key in the map in the "toolchains" attribute
cc_toolchain_suite(
  name = 'toolchain',
  toolchains = {
    'armeabi-v7a|clang': ':cc-compiler-armeabi-v7a',
     "k8|compiler": ":cc-compiler-local",
  },
)

filegroup(
  name = 'linaro_linux_all_files',
  srcs = [
    '//tools/arm_compiler/linaro_linux_gcc:clang-symlinks',
    '//tools/arm_compiler/linaro_linux_gcc:tool-wrappers',
    '@linaroLinuxGcc49Repo//:compiler_pieces',
  ],
)

filegroup(
  name = 'linaro_linux_linker_files',
  srcs = [
    '//tools/arm_compiler/linaro_linux_gcc:gcc',
    '//tools/arm_compiler/linaro_linux_gcc:ld',
    '//tools/arm_compiler/linaro_linux_gcc:ar',
    '//tools/arm_compiler/linaro_linux_gcc:clang-ld',
    '//tools/arm_compiler/linaro_linux_gcc:clang',
    '@linaroLinuxGcc49Repo//:compiler_pieces',
  ],
)

filegroup(
  name = 'linaro_linux_compiler_files',
  srcs = [
    '//tools/arm_compiler/linaro_linux_gcc:gcc',
    '//tools/arm_compiler/linaro_linux_gcc:ld',
    '//tools/arm_compiler/linaro_linux_gcc:clang',
    '//tools/arm_compiler/linaro_linux_gcc:as',
  ],
)

cc_toolchain(
  name = 'cc-compiler-armeabi-v7a',
  all_files = '//tools/arm_compiler:linaro_linux_all_files',
  compiler_files = '//tools/arm_compiler:linaro_linux_compiler_files',
  cpu = 'armeabi-v7a',
  dwp_files = ':empty',
  dynamic_runtime_libs = [':empty'],
  linker_files = '//tools/arm_compiler:linaro_linux_linker_files',
  objcopy_files = '//tools/arm_compiler/linaro_linux_gcc:objcopy',
  static_runtime_libs = [':empty'],
  strip_files = '//tools/arm_compiler/linaro_linux_gcc:strip',
  supports_param_files = 1,
)

cc_toolchain(
    name = "cc-compiler-local",
    all_files = ":empty",
    compiler_files = ":empty",
    cpu = "local",
    dwp_files = ":empty",
    dynamic_runtime_libs = [":empty"],
    linker_files = ":empty",
    objcopy_files = ":empty",
    static_runtime_libs = [":empty"],
    strip_files = ":empty",
    supports_param_files = 1,
)
```

arm_compiler/CROSSTOOL:

```
major_version: "5"
minor_version: "5"
default_target_cpu: "armeabi-v7a"

default_toolchain {
  cpu: "armeabi-v7a"
  toolchain_identifier: "clang_linux_armhf"
}

default_toolchain {
  cpu: "k8"
  toolchain_identifier: "local"
}

toolchain {
  abi_version: "clang_3.6"
  abi_libc_version: "glibc_2.19"
  builtin_sysroot: ""
  compiler: "clang"
  host_system_name: "armeabi-v7a"
  needsPic: true
  supports_gold_linker: false
  supports_incremental_linker: false
  supports_fission: false
  supports_interface_shared_objects: false
  supports_normalizing_ar: true
  supports_start_end_lib: false
  supports_thin_archives: true
  target_libc: "glibc_2.19"
  target_cpu: "armeabi-v7a"
  target_system_name: "arm_a15"
  toolchain_identifier: "clang_linux_armhf"

  tool_path { name: "ar" path: "linaro_linux_gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar" }
  tool_path { name: "compat-ld" path: "linaro_linux_gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld" }
  tool_path { name: "cpp" path: "linaro_linux_gcc/clang_bin/clang" }
  tool_path { name: "dwp" path: "linaro_linux_gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf-dwp" }
  tool_path { name: "gcc" path: "linaro_linux_gcc/clang_bin/clang" }
  tool_path { name: "gcov" path: "arm-frc-linux-gnueabi/arm-frc-linux-gnueabi-gcov-5.5" }
  # C(++) compiles invoke the compiler (as that is the one knowing where
  # to find libraries), but we provide LD so other rules can invoke the linker.
  tool_path { name: "ld" path: "linaro_linux_gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld" }
  tool_path { name: "nm" path: "linaro_linux_gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf-nm" }
  tool_path { name: "objcopy" path: "linaro_linux_gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf-objcopy" }
  objcopy_embed_flag: "-I"
  objcopy_embed_flag: "binary"
  tool_path { name: "objdump" path: "linaro_linux_gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf-objdump" }
  tool_path { name: "strip" path: "linaro_linux_gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf-strip" }

  compiler_flag: "-target"
  compiler_flag: "armv7a-arm-linux-gnueabif"
  compiler_flag: "--sysroot=external/linaroLinuxGcc49Repo/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc"
  compiler_flag: "-mfloat-abi=hard"

  compiler_flag: "-nostdinc"
  compiler_flag: "-isystem"
  compiler_flag: "/usr/lib/clang/3.6/include"
  compiler_flag: "-isystem"
  compiler_flag: "external/linaroLinuxGcc49Repo/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.5.0/include"
  compiler_flag: "-isystem"
  compiler_flag: "external/linaroLinuxGcc49Repo/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include"
  compiler_flag: "-isystem"
  compiler_flag: "external/linaroLinuxGcc49Repo/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.5.0/include-fixed"
  compiler_flag: "-isystem"
  compiler_flag: "external/linaroLinuxGcc49Repo/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include"
  cxx_flag: "-isystem"
  cxx_flag: "external/linaroLinuxGcc49Repo/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/5.5.0/arm-linux-gnueabihf"
  cxx_flag: "-isystem"
  cxx_flag: "external/linaroLinuxGcc49Repo/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/5.5.0"
  cxx_flag: "-isystem"
  cxx_flag: "external/linaroLinuxGcc49Repo/include/c++/5.5.0/arm-linux-gnueabihf"
  cxx_flag: "-isystem"
  cxx_flag: "external/linaroLinuxGcc49Repo/include/c++/5.5.0"

  cxx_builtin_include_directory: "%package(@linaroLinuxGcc49Repo)%//include"
  cxx_builtin_include_directory: "%package(@linaroLinuxGcc49Repo)%//arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include"
  cxx_builtin_include_directory: "%package(@linaroLinuxGcc49Repo)%//arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib/include"
  cxx_builtin_include_directory: "%package(@linaroLinuxGcc49Repo)%//arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.5.0/include-fixed"
  cxx_builtin_include_directory: "%package(@linaroLinuxGcc49Repo)%//include/c++/5.5.0"
  cxx_builtin_include_directory: "%package(@linaroLinuxGcc49Repo)%//arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.5.0/include"
  cxx_builtin_include_directory: "%package(@linaroLinuxGcc49Repo)%//arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.5.0/include-fixed"
  cxx_builtin_include_directory: "%package(@linaroLinuxGcc49Repo)%//lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.5.0/include"
  cxx_builtin_include_directory: "%package(@linaroLinuxGcc49Repo)%//lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.5.0/include-fixed"
  cxx_builtin_include_directory: "%package(@linaroLinuxGcc49Repo)%//arm-linux-gnueabihf/include)%/c++/5.5.0"
  cxx_builtin_include_directory: '/usr/lib/clang/3.6/include'

  linker_flag: "-target"
  linker_flag: "armv7a-arm-linux-gnueabif"
  linker_flag: "--sysroot=external/linaroLinuxGcc49Repo/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc"
  linker_flag: "-lstdc++"
  linker_flag: "-Ltools/arm_compiler/linaro_linux_gcc/clang_more_libs"
  linker_flag: "-Lexternal/linaroLinuxGcc49Repo/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib"
  linker_flag: "-Lexternal/linaroLinuxGcc49Repo/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/lib"
  linker_flag: "-Lexternal/linaroLinuxGcc49Repo/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib"
  linker_flag: "-Lexternal/linaroLinuxGcc49Repo/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin"
  linker_flag: "-Wl,--dynamic-linker=/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3"

  # Anticipated future default.
  # This makes GCC and Clang do what we want when called through symlinks.
  unfiltered_cxx_flag: "-no-canonical-prefixes"
  linker_flag: "-no-canonical-prefixes"

  # Make C++ compilation deterministic. Use linkstamping instead of these
  # compiler symbols.
  unfiltered_cxx_flag: "-Wno-builtin-macro-redefined"
  unfiltered_cxx_flag: "-D__DATE__=\"redacted\""
  unfiltered_cxx_flag: "-D__TIMESTAMP__=\"redacted\""
  unfiltered_cxx_flag: "-D__TIME__=\"redacted\""

  # Security hardening on by default.
  # Conservative choice; -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 may be unsafe in some cases.
  # We need to undef it before redefining it as some distributions now have
  # it enabled by default.
  compiler_flag: "-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE"
  compiler_flag: "-fstack-protector"
  compiler_flag: "-fPIE"
  linker_flag: "-pie"
  linker_flag: "-Wl,-z,relro,-z,now"

  # Enable coloring even if there's no attached terminal. Bazel removes the
  # escape sequences if --nocolor is specified.
  compiler_flag: "-fdiagnostics-color=always"

    # All warnings are enabled. Maybe enable -Werror as well?
  compiler_flag: "-Wall"
  # Enable a few more warnings that aren't part of -Wall.
  compiler_flag: "-Wunused-but-set-parameter"
  # But disable some that are problematic.
  compiler_flag: "-Wno-free-nonheap-object" # has false positives

  # Keep stack frames for debugging, even in opt mode.
  compiler_flag: "-fno-omit-frame-pointer"

  # Stamp the binary with a unique identifier.
  linker_flag: "-Wl,--build-id=md5"
  linker_flag: "-Wl,--hash-style=gnu"

  compilation_mode_flags {
    mode: DBG
    # Enable debug symbols.
    compiler_flag: "-g"
  }
  compilation_mode_flags {
    mode: OPT

    # No debug symbols.
    # Maybe we should enable https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DebugFission for opt or
    # even generally? However, that can't happen here, as it requires special
    # handling in Bazel.
    compiler_flag: "-g0"

    # Conservative choice for -O
    # -O3 can increase binary size and even slow down the resulting binaries.
    # Profile first and / or use FDO if you need better performance than this.
    compiler_flag: "-O2"

    # Disable assertions
    compiler_flag: "-DNDEBUG"
```

Comment: This sounds like it should be a github issue